# Probability statement not clear

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, order-statistics

> *Maximum order statistic of a random sample from a U[0,θ] distribution*
>
> Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be a sequence of i.i.d. uniform random variables on $[0,\theta]$. Let $X(n)=\max_{1≤k≤n} X(k)$. The distribution of $X(n)$ is
>
> $$P(X(n)≤x)=(x/θ)^n.$$
>
> (Note that by a very simple argument, **this actually also shows that $X(n) \to \theta$** **in probability**, and even, **almost surely**, if the random variables are all defined on the same space.)

1) I understand the first **bold** statement as that as $X(n) \to \theta$, $P(X(n)≤x) \to 1$. Am I right?

2) But then, what does the "*almost surely*" part mean?

3) Also, it says "*if the random variables are all defined on the same space.*" But is it possible otherwise if we were told: "Let $X_1,X_2, \dots$ be a sequence of i.i.d. uniform random variables on $[0,\theta]$"? Thus, all random variables come from the same sample space, don't they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not already familiar with the measure-theoretic definition of "probability space", I would suggest you look up the Kolmogorov axioms for probability before continuing with this answer.

$X_n \to \theta$ in probability means that for all $\epsilon>0$, $P(|X_n-\theta|>\epsilon) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. $X_n \to \theta$ almost surely means that $P \left ( X_n \to \theta \right )=1$. The latter is stronger. Convergence almost surely only makes sense if $X_n$ are defined on the same probability space, because it requires a notion of pointwise limits (so you need to fix a $\omega \in \Omega$ and then look at the existence/value of $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n(\omega)$).

If the random variables have a *joint* distribution (e.g. if they are independent), then they must indeed be defined on the same space. But you could have a sequence of $U[0,\theta]$ random variables each defined on their own probability space. There just would be no joint distribution in this circumstance.

As for understanding the text at hand, it seems to boil down to: "the pdf of the $n$th maximum is this. Given any sequence of random variables with this sequence of pdfs, they converge in probability to $\theta$. If they are defined on the same probability space, then they also converge almost surely". In other words, in the middle they seem to be forgetting that in context, to make sense of the order statistic in the first place, the random variables *already* must be defined on the same probability space. All of the individual statements are correct, but this loss of context makes the presentation rather confusing.

Comment: The OP is right: it is odd to specify the condition "if the random variables are all defined on the same space" since from the moment one defines $X_{(n)}$, this condition is implicitely assumed to hold. Unless every $X_k$ is defined on the same probability space, the definition $X_{(n)}=\max\limits_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}X_k$ does not even make sense. Or, one would define $X_{(n)}=\max\limits_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}X_k^n$ for some $(X_k^n)_k$ defined on $\Omega_n$, and then the condition that every $\Omega_n$ is the same is useful (but this is not what is written in the question).

Comment: @Did I agree that the maximum doesn't make sense if the original r.v.s were defined on the same space. I think the quoted text was (confusingly) forgetting about the original context and just saying "if you have a sequence of random variables with these pdfs, they do this".

Comment: Typo: "if the original r.v.s were *not* defined on the same space" (or "*only* makes sense if...")

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: @Ian: could you please explain how a sequence of U[0,θ] random variables can be each defined on their own probability space? My logic: the prob.function will be the same as uniform distr. on the same interval. A sample space as well as the interval for all is [0,θ]. Thus, F should also be equal...

Comment: @Lola So strictly speaking, from the perspective of Kolmogorov's formalism, there is nothing interesting going on. That's because to Kolmogorov, a random variable is a function from a probability space to $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{R}^n$, or in general any measurable space). So you can have a sequence of $U[0,\theta]$ random variables that map from different probability spaces or from the same probability space.

Comment: @Lola (Cont.) Strictly speaking the easiest way to realize a $U[0,\theta]$ random variable is to make your probability space be $[0,\theta]$ with the normalized Lebesgue measure and define $X(\omega)=\omega$, but that is not essential. Even if it were, you can always make *copies* of $\mathbb{R}$ and have those copies be the domains of your different random variables.

Comment: @Lola (Cont.) The main "real" thing that changes between the case of random variables on different probability spaces vs. the same probability space is that in the first situation there is no such thing as a joint distribution. In the second situation there is necessarily a joint distribution. Most notions of convergence of random variables require them to be defined on the same probability space, but not all of them. The main one which does not require this is convergence in distribution.

Comment: @Lola (Cont.) Notably, convergence in distribution to a *constant* is the same as convergence in probability (which is related to what your quoted text above is talking about). Sorry for all these comments, both Lola and mods...perhaps some of this should be in the answer.